# Symfony 3 not getting Dropzone's file

Tags: symfony, dropzone.js

Ok, so I decided to integrate dropzone with symfony 3.  I encountered an issue in my controller.

This works and it is able to get the uploaded file:

```
 $file = $_FILES['file'];
```

But this one doesn't, it returns null or empty

```
$file = $request->files->get('file');
```

And since I am using symfony, then I guess it would really make sense to make use of symfony's way of getting the files.  Only am not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Please post more of your code to be clear - form that uploads file would be nice

Comment: Will need to see more code to help you.If you want to look at a working implementation of dropzone in symfony checkout https://github.com/libre-informatique/SymfonyLibrinfoMediaBundle

Comment: as mentioned, please provide more code.

Comment: Ok, so one thing I realised is that dumping `$request->files->get('file')` returns empty but I went on and move the file away and there it is.